# Bot Framework Calling Bot on Skype: where is the dial pad to respond to number input?

Tags: c#, botframework, skype, ivr

So, I have setup the demo from Microsoft, where they have a IVR bot example.
I ca nactually reach it over skype Web version or my mobile device (the desktop app is not enabling the call button yet).
I hear the text I have entered, then being asked to enter the number 1.
However, no dial pad is shown in the call, just pressing my keyboard is not working, and the general dial pad of course isn't either

Any ideas on this? This is how the web version looks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the dial pad is a function of Skype and not bot framework. You will need to reach out to the Skype team regarding implementation at every level as the dial pad can be found on Microsoft Store app version.

Comment: Okay, however, I would assume it is the bot framework that is sending specific JSON object to the SKype API to control available buttons. The call button is enabled after setting up IVR 1:1 on the bot, Video is enabled when configuring the Media option in Bot setup. So, that is why i directed the question to bot framework, as implementation is not done directly to Skype API

Comment: I should clarify "at every level": it's a function that is available on some versions of Skype. For instance, Skype Desktop makes the dial pad available. However, it is not available in Skype downloaded via the MS Store. Hence, the request needs to be made with the Skype team for full implementation.